# How can I create a mobile child theme in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, themes

I've created a child theme in Wordpress using the tutorial here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

When visiting my site from a mobile device, there appears to be a different CSS applied which I cannot find anywhere to edit. I'm wondering how I can edit this mobile CSS file or create my own child version of it.

link to site: http://taber.bensullins.com

Answer (score 1):

Your Parent theme, Ari responsive CSS starts at line 801 in style.css. You see :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 870px) { }
```

Styles in this query will be applied when a viewing in that resolution.

Further on there are some more @media's, line 876 & 907